# If statement doesn't work with timeout function inside

Tags: jquery, if-statement, timeout

I am trying to delay some actions inside my function. They work normally but when i try to include them inside *timeout function* my *if statement* `if( percent > 50)` doesn't work. It does it for all elements, not just once with percent higher then 50. I also tried with `.delay(3000)`, it doesn't work.

```
if (percent > 50) {
  $(this).addClass("gt-50").delay(3000);
  $(".gt-50").children('.ppc-progress').css('clip','rect(0px, '+ widthhalf +'px, '+ width +'px, 0px) ').delay(3000);
  $(".gt-50").children('.ppc-progress').children('.ppc-progress-fill').css('clip','rect(0px, '+ width +'px, '+ width +'px, '+ widthhalf +'px) ').delay(3000);
}
```

So conclusion, either *if statement* works either *timeout function*, I cant accomplish both of them to work. Have any idea?

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  $( ".progress-pie-chart" ).each(function(  ) {

    percent = parseInt($(this).data('percent'));

    var width = $(this).width();
    var widthhalf = width / 2;

    if (percent > 50) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        $(".progress-pie-chart").addClass("gt-50");
        $(".gt-50").children('.ppc-progress').css('clip','rect(0px, '+ widthhalf +'px, '+ width +'px, 0px) ');
        $(".gt-50").children('.ppc-progress').children('.ppc-progress-fill').css('clip','rect(0px, '+ width +'px, '+ width +'px, '+ widthhalf +'px) ');
      }, 3000);
    }
    $( this ).css('height',''+ width +'px');
    $( this ).children('.ppc-progress').children('.ppc-progress-fill').css('transform','rotate('+ deg +'deg)');
    $( this ).children('.ball-holder').css('transform','rotate('+ deg +'deg)');
    $( this ).children('.ppc-progress').css('clip','rect(0px, '+ width +'px, '+ width +'px, '+ widthhalf +'px) ');
    $( this ).children('.ppc-progress').children('.ppc-progress-fill').css('clip','rect(0px, '+ widthhalf +'px, '+ width +'px, 0px) ');
    $('.summ-cont').css('top',''+ -widthhalf +'px');
  });
});
```

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces this.

Comment: How can you even code like this? Hard to understand a $h!t without indentation! `:(`

Comment: What does **doesn't work** mean? What's not working, this should work after 3 seconds.

Comment: `.bind(this)` after what? `:O`

Comment: @A.Wolff Does it work? Haven't seen such a binding.

Comment: Gosh. I am stupid. `:D`

Comment: @PraveenKumar And now that the code is indented, yhis is no more relevant... :)

Comment: You need to use a closure for `width` & `widthhalf `

Comment: Thank you for your answers and sorry if the code is not clear enough. Yes it works after 3 seconds but for all items, not just for once higher than 50 percent.

Comment: So **if statement** doesn't work. But it works this way, without timeout function:
`if (percent > 50) {
        $(this).addClass("gt-50");
        $(".gt-50").children('.ppc-progress').css('clip','rect(0px, '+ widthhalf +'px, '+ width +'px, 0px) ');
        $(".gt-50").children('.ppc-progress').children('.ppc-progress-fill').css('clip','rect(0px, '+ width +'px, '+ width +'px, '+ widthhalf +'px) ');
      }`  .  When i put timeout inside it, it doesn't work. Width and widthhalf work fine.

Comment: `if (percent > 50) {

$(this).delay(3000).queue(function(){
       
        $(this).addClass("gt-50");
       $(".gt-50").children('.ppc-progress').css('clip','rect(0px, '+ widthhalf +'px, '+ width +'px, 0px) ');
$(".gt-50").children('.ppc-progress').children('.ppc-progress-fill').css('clip','rect(0px, '+ width +'px, '+ width +'px, '+ widthhalf +'px) ');
    });
}`                                                                                                                        I solved it with delay function. Thanks for help.